# windows scrollbars changed to very thin, registry changes keep reverting

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, windows-registry, scrollbar

Suddenly vertical and horizontal scrollbars became very thin. Impossible to read excel tab names as they are in the scrollbar.
Changing the Registry entry as advised in [How to Customize the Scrollbars on Windows 10 and 11](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-11-customize-scrollbars/) didn't work. Each time I rebooted, the new thin value reappeared in the Registry.
DSIM and scandisk didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by system restore.  Possibly the latest windows update caused it.
[image: restore]